# Modern C++ idiomatic way of using poll()/epoll()/select()

Tags: c++, c++17

for networking, we have `asio` which gives a high level, platform independent asynchronous communication over sockets. Is there an equivalent for good old `poll()`, `epoll()`, or `select()`?

Basically, I'd like to be able to wait for events on an `ifstream`, if possible.

Thanks

Comment: Whether you poll or not has nothing to do with C++. It can be a valid strategy if libraries don't proved callbacks and/or notifications. What you can do in a c++ manner is that you poll using an asynchronous task. E.g. use std::async/std::future and a std::condition_variable with timed waits (poll interval) that also waits for a poll suspend or poll end condition. (it's too late in the day to write you an example). I think it will also involve https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek

Comment: Sadly there is no standard solution that I am aware of. Remember that C++'s IO streams are incredibly stupid because they have to work exactly the same across a very wide set of possible targets with very different hardware and system support.